# Is there any way to find out how often a certain query is sent to a search engine?

Tags: search-engines, statistics, seo-software

For example, let's assume a string 'green apple'. Is there at least one SE (or, maybe 3rd-party site) which provides its statistics on how often do users search this concrete string?

Answer (score 3):

It's highly doubtful any engine will provide actual *numbers* for this information, but [Google Trends](http://www.google.com/trends) does provide enough to get a feel for a term's recent performance. Whether that's useful will obviously depend upon how precise you really want this information to be.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [Google Adwords Tool](https://adwords.google.com/o/Targeting/Explorer)

Comment: +1 - Also worth mentioning: the Adwords tool offers Global and Local approximations which are particularly useful, as the results generated by the tool can be exported in a variety of formats for tracking over time.

Answer (score 3):

And here's another tool: [Google Insights for Search](http://www.google.com/insights/search/#)  
it helps you to compare search volume patterns across specific regions, categories, time frames and properties.