# How can i find keywords or phrase which fetch less than 100 or even no results, without manually doing it?

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search, research

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to find out how often a certain query is sent to a search engine?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19576/is-there-any-way-to-find-out-how-often-a-certain-query-is-sent-to-a-search-engine)

How can i find keywords or phrase which fetch less than 100 or even no results, without manually doing it?

I know it will take time for any person to go manually research.

Any tool paid or free.

**"Time is money"**

Comment: Do you write your pages for people or for search engines?

Comment: @su, this is very specific.

Comment: @martinstoeckli, I write for people, however the keyword trend demands change, so I am asking.

Comment: Actually, I did misread the question being about results vs. queries. Trashed the notification comment, but I can't undo the vote at the moment. It'll take several more people for it to actually close, anyway.

Comment: @su, it's okay!!! Thank for replying to my comments. Any thought about the asked question?